# Rails 4: rails-jquery-autocomplete not showing suggestion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete

I am trying to create a text input field with autocomplete with rails's rails-jquery-autocomplete. I tried to follow the instruction on this page step-by-step: https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete, but I was no able to get the input filed to show any suggested text. Can someone please help me to identify where I have done wrong? Thanks in advance.

The following are a snippet of my code:

Controller:

```
class LabController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :ingredient, :name

  def index
    @recipe = Recipe.where(station: "Laboratory")

  end
end
```

View:

```
.container
  = autocomplete_field_tag 'test', '', autocomplete_ingredient_name_lab_index_path
```

Route:

```
resources :lab, only: [:index, :show] do
    get :autocomplete_ingredient_name, :on => :collection
  end
```

database:

```
create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end
```

Comment: Is there any error on console?

Comment: Instead of `gem 'rails-jquery-autocomplete'` you can use  Token Fields http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields, it's very easy to integrate and lightweight.

Comment: Hav you required jquery, jquery_ujs, jquery-ui/autocomplete, autocomplete-rails in your application.js
https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete#rails-4-and-higher

Comment: @HiteshSongra No error in the console. I will look into Token Fields in the mean time. Thanks!

Comment: @Deepak I did required  jquery, jquery_ujs, jquery-ui/autocomplete, autocomplete-rails. However, the only difference i made is using jquery-ui instead of jquery-ui/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the rout, you should follow these steps

controller:

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :category, :name
end
```

View:

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_list, autocomplete_category_name_artists_path %>
```

Route:

```
resources :artists do
 get :autocomplete_category_name, on: :collection
end
```